# K8S Audit changes are not being saved in master after restart

Tags: kubernetes, audit

i created K8S cluster (unmanaged) in google cloud.
i added the following changes in the master:

--audit-dynamic-configuration --feature-gates=DynamicAuditing=true --runtime-config=auditregistration.k8s.io/v1alpha1=true

as written in :
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/

and everything is working as expected.
but after restart these settings are not being saved.

anyone encounter this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using kubeadm, this is how you apply flags to the apiserver (all of these changes should be done on the master node)

1. Edit the following file: `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` and add these flags to the list of flags:

```
--audit-dynamic-configuration
--feature-gates=DynamicAuditing=true
--runtime-config=auditregistration.k8s.io/v1alpha1=true
```

Note that every change done to the kube-apiserver manifest causes the apiserver to restart.

2. Once it is up and running execute the following command to verify flags are all set and server is up and running: `ps -ef | grep kube-apiserver`. The output should contain the flags you applied.

In case of issues, see the kube-apiserver logs placed at `/var/log/containers/` and search for files beginning with `kube-apiserver`.

Comment: thanks for your answer! i made the changes in  "kube-apiserver.manifest" i dont see "kube-apiserver.yaml". i did all of the above and its works. but after restart everything is being reset.

Comment: how did you install your cluster? kubeadm? minikube? please search for the yaml file: `find / -name="kube-apiserver.yaml"` and see if it exists. you can also run a general search and supply the output: `find / -name "*apiserver*"` so we can look into it. another options is to see if the apiserver is running `--config` flag by using the `ps -ef | grep kube-apiserver` command and see what file it references

Comment: i download the tar from [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/releases) and run following the instractions here: [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/turnkey/gce/) . i didnt use  kubeadm/ minikube. I run the search for the yaml and i dont have this file. the ps command result is: **/usr/local/bin/kube-apiserver**

Comment: the ps command should also return the arguments taken by this process, you don't get any?

Comment: could it be that you are not searching for the yaml file **on the master node itself?** did you try to run `find / -name "*apiserver*"` on the master node?